# How to change the branch a commit is associated with in Git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, bitbucket

Currently I am using Bitbucket to store the files and branches in Git. Unfortunately, I seem to keep reassociating existing branches with new branches, so where below only the top one should be on the `feature/availabilityfix` branch, instead it has also associated all the ones below which were/still are on the `feature/searchfix` branch.

Is it possible to disassociate all those ones from the `feature/availabilityfix` branch from this other one? I'm completely confused by it!

Also when I merged the previous feature branch back into `develop`, it has now put that on as a branch for those files. Is that the correct way of dealing with files when merging?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commit is not "associated" with a branch, it is contained in one (or multiple).

Lets assume you have one branch "develop" which contains commit A. Commit A added file "foo.txt". You now create a new branch "featureX" based on the latest commit in "develop".

Commit A is now contained in the branches "develop" and "featureX". If that wouldn't be the case, branch "featureX" wouldn't contain the file "foo.txt".

Comment: What I don't understand though is why when featureX is merged into develop stream, and then featureY is created, all those that were within featureX become part of the featureY stream?

Comment: @Ollie: For exactly the reasons I outlined above. "featureY" is based on the current state of "develop". The current state of "develop" contains all commits from "featureX", so naturally, "featureY" now must also contain those commits. Otherwise "featureY" wouldn't contain the changes introduced by "featureX".

Comment: You are looking at this the wrong way. For every commit, ask yourself: "Does the change that was introduced by this commit exist in the branch I am wondering about?"

Comment: So say you introduce six new features over a week, featureA to featureF. Should all the commits in that first feature be listed as also being part of all six feature branches?

Comment: Commits are neither associated nor contained in a branch. A branch is a tag, that is 'glued' to commit. The difference to a tag is that it advances when you make a consecutive commit.

Comment: Okay, so when a feature is completed it should be pulled into the main develop branch and then closed/deleted?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad: Is that the reason for the downvote? If so, please remove the downvote as it is unjustified. I quote the text in the commit view of Git Extensions: "Contained in branches: develop, feature/Z3_access". Or the syntax of git branch to check whether a commit is *contained* within a branch: `git branch --contains 50f3754`.

Comment: @Ollie: Normally you delete the feature branch after it has been merged into "develop".